# NetworkOnMainThreadException for register function

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming and I am trying to create a register and login function with php, mysql and sqlite. I am having this error after I clicked the register or login button. How do I fix this?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
      at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
      at my.fyp.classifieds.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
      at my.fyp.classifieds.library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:59)
      at my.fyp.inticlassifieds.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:80)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not sure which class is causing the error. This is the Register class:

```
public class Register extends Activity {
Button btnRegister, btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword, inputCPassword;
EditText inputContact;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_CONTACT = "contact";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields     
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    inputCPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);
    inputContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerContact);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLogin);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirmpass = inputCPassword.getText().toString();

            //Check all fields      
            if(inputContact.length()<10)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Please Enter correct mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
             if(inputPassword.length()<6)
             {              
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Please Enter minimum 6 characters in password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
             } 
             if(!password.equals(confirmpass))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return;
             }
             if(inputEmail.length()<6)
             {              
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Please Enter valid email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
             }

            String contact = inputContact.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            //String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(email,contact,password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_CONTACT), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    });

    // Link to Login Screen
   /* public void btnLinkToLogin(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent (this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity (i);
        finish();
    }*/

  btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

This is UserFunctions class:

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/project/index.php";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/project/index.php";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String email, String contact, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", contact));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException occurs when you attempt to perform network activity on the main thread. Create a new thread for networking activity. I believe it is this line: `jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl()` causing the issues.

Comment: Check out this link [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception). It explains how you should make `Network` calls on a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` and not on the `UIThread`

Comment: On ANR and what triggers it: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: where should i put the AsyncTask?

Comment: As as inner class or a separate class whichever satisfies your requirement

Answer (score 0):

//The lazy way of handling this is to turn the check of:
   //You can put below code on create

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);